# Problem in Helptext rendering due to showheader attribute in apex:page

Tags: apex, visualforce

i am displaying helptext with some fields but when i do showHeader="false" in apex:page,as i want to remove my header.all helptext disappears from my page.Why this is happening?How can i prevent from this?

Comment: If showheader="false" then it does not display helpText. In this case you can create Custom Help Text. Try following link http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Need-help-with-help-bubble-on-VF-page/m-p/596177#M62347

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the showHeader attribute to false takes out the javascript that displays the help text.

The final entry on this thread:

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/showHeader-quot-false-quot-inputField-help-text-lost/td-p/163419

has a solution that uses CSS to hide the header information:

```
<style type="text/css">
.bPageHeader {
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

which I've just tried on my dev org and works.  However, this has an element of fragility, as if Salesforce change the style class for the header, it will suddenly re-appear.

Answer (score 0):

Nice one.
We may need to add the following as well, if communities are enabled.

.globalHeaderBar
{
display:none;
}